# Eclipse & Dark Juno - any way to make the console and other features dark?

Tags: java, eclipse

Dark Juno really makes Eclipse look nice, but I find some of the UI elements, such as minimized perspectives and the console are glaringly white still, which is really hard on the eyes. Is it possible to change this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these colour preferences come from your operating system.  This is one of the annoying things about the Eclipse colour preferences - what is in eclipse, what is in the OS.  I really wish they would ignore all the OS colours for a more consistent look.

So, one solution is to set those colours in your OS.  How you do that depends on your OS though.  This can be problematic though, since it might make other applications look strange/unreadable.

You can override the console colour in Eclipse though:  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm

> Fonts and colors in Eclipse
>
> Eclipse uses the fonts and colors provided by the operating system as
>   much as possible. On Windows the platform color and font settings are
>   found on the Preferences > Colors and Fonts page. The font used by
>   most widgets in Eclipse is the one set in the Message Box settings of
>   the properties. However, operating systems do not provide enough
>   colors to handle all of the extra information that colors and fonts
>   provide in Eclipse.
>
> To set the types of output (and their colors) in the Console view:
>
> Open the   Run/Debug > Console preference page. Checking the Show when
>   program writes to standard out checkbox will make the Console view
>   visible each time new output is written to the console from the
>   program's standard output stream. If there is no Console view in the
>   current perspective, one will be created. Checking the Show when
>   program writes to standard err checkbox will make the Console view
>   visible each time new output is written to the console from the
>   program's standard error stream. If there is no Console view in the
>   current perspective, one will be created. Click any of the color
>   buttons to change the color for the corresponding text stream.   To
>   set the fonts used in the Console view:
>
> Open the   General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts preference page.
>   Select Console font from the Debug category and use the Change...
>   button to change the font.  (The Detail Pane Text Font can be used to
>   change the font of the debugger's default Detail Pane).